# Are the functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^2 $ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, g(x)=x^3$ open mappings?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My questions are the following:

Is the mapping $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^2$ open?

Is the mapping $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^3$ open?

I would appreciate if you could explain how to answer those questions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: For $f$, is $f(\mathbb{R})$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$? For $g$, it is easy to show that it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: For $f$, $f((-a,a))=[0,a^2)$

Comment: Is it correct that f: R -> R, f(x)=x^2 is not open due to Senna's answer? Maybe it would be an open mapping if the domain was (0,infinity) in stead of all of R?

Comment: Yes. Senna's answer shows f cannot be open since f can map an open set to a set which is clearly not open.

Comment: Intuitively, by looking at a plot of g it is reasonable to conclude that g is an open map. Thus, let me consider Mindlack's answer that it is easy to show that f is a homeomorphism. So, the function g: R -> R, g(x)=x^3 is clearly surjective and injective, i.e. g is bijective. Therefore, the inverse exists and from the open mapping theorem g^{-1} is continuous as well and we condlude that g is a homeomorphism. To show that g: R -> R, g(x)=x^3 is a homeomorphism, is that enough to conclude that g is an open mapping?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f((-1, 1)) = [0, 1)$, which is not open. So $f$ is not open. On the other hand, $g$ is a homeomorphism (with inverse $y \mapsto y^{1/3}$), so $g$ is open.

Comment: Thanks a lot - It makes sense to me!